# Syntaxerror: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 16

Tags: sql, derby

I'm trying to learn SQL via SQL tutorials on Youtube and none of the commands/functions are working for me.

I am experiencing a syntax error:

```
Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 16.

select getdate()
           ^

1 statement failed.
```

I have tried with and without ";" but always getting the same result.

```
SELECT GETDATE();
```

I would've expected to see the current date but it doesn't work. I'm pretty sure its something super simple but I just can't see it.

Comment: most sql environments (besides sqlserver) require you to include a from <tablename> here.

Comment: [As documented in the manual](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/ref/rrefsqlj29026.html) there is no function `getdate()` in Derby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of "**dual**", in IBM lingo, I believe the dummy table is called **SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1**.

Try this:

```
select current_date from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Comment: @Hogan Why is it better in this case?

Comment: This works indeed but I still dont understand why Im not able to use all the SQL functions like day(), year(), convert(), getdate() etc.. Thank you!

Comment: @GenWan --- sysibm.sysdummy1 is implemented as a null view.  it requires the engine to access the data store for meta information etc.  values is the native "table constructor" and should be faster.  also values is an sql standard and sysdummy is not.

Comment: @Flippi: your random videos on youtube probably don't deal with Derby. It's better to read the manual for your DBMS product rather than relying on some random videos.

Comment: @Flippi day(), year(), conver(), getdate() they are not the standard SQL functions. For example, in oracle you cannot use year() or day() or getdate(). But in T-SQL you can use them. You need to use the function regarding which DBMS you are using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I thought there is no difference in the environment. SQL is SQL isnt it? I would have expected that derby supports all SQL commands/functions if its a SQL environment. I can access the derbyDB either with powershell/ij.bat file or with the SQL workbench.. how can I use functions such as GETDATE(), YEAR(), DAY() etc? Or are the functions different than SQL standard? thank you

Comment: @GenWan Thank you!  I just found this https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/ref/index.html , a list with all the "built in functions" thank you thank you!

Comment: @Flippi You are welcome. Please accept any answer you like to close this issue.

Comment: Well `year()` or `getdate()´ are not part of the SQL standard to begin with. If you want to focus on standard SQL, stay away from tutorials that deal with MySQL or SQL Server. Postgres might be a better choice then.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following statement is better in this case

```
values( current date ) ;
```

but it depends on what platform you are using.

Comment: I am using SQL workbench.. yes it works. But my real question is why can't I use all the SQL functions such as year(), day(), convert(), getdate()..?

Comment: because those are not the correct functions on db2 @flippi.  look at a db2 manual for details on date functions

Comment: @flippi -- read this: https://developer.ibm.com/articles/fun-with-dates-and-times/